# Sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac1{(2n+1)^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

What is the value of the sum $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac1{(2n+1)^3}$$

I think the sum evaluates to $\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}-\frac1{32}\zeta(3,-\frac1{4})$, where the last zeta is the Hurwitz zeta function. But, Hurwitz zeta is defined only for $\operatorname{Re}(q)>0$ as a Dirichlet series in this manner. Am I right? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Did you mean instead for the $(1)^{n-1}$ to be in the summand?

Comment: Note: I have put the $(-1)^{n-1}$ within the summation. This is not what the OP had originally written but I assume is what they meant.